# Merging two pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have one dataframe, `A`, that looks like this:

```
+---+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+-------+
|   |    time    |    uid    |   o_uid   | msg | count |
+---+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+-------+
| 0 | 1433131357 | 191470529 | 191159572 | eis |     1 |
| 1 | 1433131410 | 191458009 | 160429326 | eis |     1 |
| 2 | 1433131504 | 191470523 | 153734142 | eis |     1 |
| 3 | 1433131685 | 191470551 | 191470546 | eis |     1 |
| 4 | 1433131782 | 191470565 | 187367195 | eis |     1 |
+---+------------+-----------+-----------+-----+-------+
```

And another dataframe, `B`, that looks like this:

```
+---+------------+-----------+-------+
|   |    time    |    uid    | count |
+---+------------+-----------+-------+
| 0 | 1433131967 | 191470529 |     1 |
| 1 | 1433132503 | 191466638 |     1 |
| 2 | 1433139333 | 191451858 |     1 |
| 3 | 1433141249 | 191470551 |     1 |
| 4 | 1433143867 | 191471209 |     1 |
+---+------------+-----------+-------+
```

What I would like to do is take all that timestamps from `B` and place them in a column in `A` where the `UIDs` match.  Where there is no match, there should be a `NaN`

I tried this: `df = pd.merge(A, B, left_on='uid', right_on='uid', how='outer')`

But I think it only appended `B` to the bottom of `A`.  It did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your time and count columns overlap in both DataFrames, so you need to supply `suffixes` as a parameter.  In the example below, I use a null suffix for `df_a` and `'_b'` as the suffix for `df_b`.

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
                     'msg': {0: 'eis', 1: 'eis', 2: 'eis', 3: 'eis', 4: 'eis'},
                     'o_uid': {0: 191159572, 1: 160429326, 2: 153734142, 3: 191470546, 4: 187367195},
                     'time': {0: 1433131357, 1: 1433131410, 2: 1433131504, 3: 1433131685, 4: 1433131782},
                     'uid': {0: 191470529, 1: 191458009, 2: 191470523, 3: 191470551, 4: 191470565}})

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
                     'time': {0: 1433131967, 1: 1433132503, 2: 1433139333, 3: 1433141249, 4: 1433143867},
                     'uid': {0: 191470529, 1: 191466638, 2: 191451858, 3: 191470551, 4: 191471209}})

>>> df_a.merge(df_b, how='outer', on='uid', suffixes=['', '_b'])
   count  msg      o_uid        time        uid  count_b      time_b
0      1  eis  191159572  1433131357  191470529        1  1433131967
1      1  eis  160429326  1433131410  191458009      NaN         NaN
2      1  eis  153734142  1433131504  191470523      NaN         NaN
3      1  eis  191470546  1433131685  191470551        1  1433141249
4      1  eis  187367195  1433131782  191470565      NaN         NaN
5    NaN  NaN        NaN         NaN  191466638        1  1433132503
6    NaN  NaN        NaN         NaN  191451858        1  1433139333
7    NaN  NaN        NaN         NaN  191471209        1  1433143867
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `left_join` is most appropriate in your case. This can be achieved by setting `how=left`

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ============================

print(df_A)

Out[33]: 
          time        uid      o_uid    msg  count

0   1433131357  191470529  191159572   eis       1
1   1433131410  191458009  160429326   eis       1
2   1433131504  191470523  153734142   eis       1
3   1433131685  191470551  191470546   eis       1
4   1433131782  191470565  187367195   eis       1

print(df_B)

Out[35]: 
         time          uid       count

0      1433131967    191470529       1
1      1433132503    191466638       1
2      1433139333    191451858       1
3      1433141249    191470551       1
4      1433143867    191471209       1

# processing
# ============================
df = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, left_on='uid', right_on='uid',how='left', suffixes=['_A', '_B'])

Out[45]: 
       time_A        uid      o_uid    msg  count_A      time_B  count_B
0  1433131357  191470529  191159572   eis         1  1.4331e+09        1
1  1433131410  191458009  160429326   eis         1         NaN      NaN
2  1433131504  191470523  153734142   eis         1         NaN      NaN
3  1433131685  191470551  191470546   eis         1  1.4331e+09        1
4  1433131782  191470565  187367195   eis         1         NaN      NaN
```